# "As low as" label still displayed after swatch selected

Tags: swatches, magento2.2.6, luma-theme

I have a problem in the category products view. I have configurable products as well, for those the swatches and a "As low as [price]" is displayed initially. Which is exactly what i want.

When i select a swatch (or all required options, but i only have one) i expect the "As low as"-Label to disappear (because the price is determined) now. But it doesn't, it stays visible. In fact the js is inserting a `display: inline`-style on the label.

The same workflow, for the same product works just fine in the product detail view (select swatch -> "As low as" disappears).

I am using luma theme with a fresh installation. Magento 2.2.6 and PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

try reindex by running `php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_flat` command